# Knowledge of meanings of Hebrew names in Daniel

Tags: hebrew, names, daniel-book-of

I have being doing a study on Daniel and the meanings of the names of Daniel and his friends and wondered how these would be understood between the friends. For example my name is Stephen, meaning crown, but very few people would know that so it would not come to mind as they used my name. However, in the Bible we often read that a person or place name signifies something else - a quality of G-d, etc.

So, since the friends were in exile and having their names changed, would it be apparent and a reminder to them of the meaning of their Hebrew names as they addressed one another?

Comment: Steve, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this fascinating question! I hope you'll take a look around and find other material of interest, perhaps starting with our six other [Daniel](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daniel-book-of) questions or our 239 other [tag:names] questions.